# Is IEnumerable.Any faster than a for loop with a break?

Tags: c#, performance, loops, ienumerable

We experienced some slowness in our code opening a form and it was possibly due to a `for` loop with a `break` that was taking a long time to execute.  I switched this to an `IEnumerable.Any()` and saw the form open very quickly.  I am now trying to figure out if making this change alone increased performance or if it was accessing the `ProductIDs` property more efficiently. Should this implementation be faster, and if so, why?

Original Implementation:

```
public bool ContainsProduct(int productID) {
    bool containsProduct = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.ProductIDs.Length; i++) {
        if (productID == this.ProductIDs[i]) {
            containsProduct = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return containsProduct;
}
```

New Implementation:

```
public bool ContainsProduct(int productID) {
    return this.ProductIDs.Any(t => productID == t);
}
```

Comment: have you profiled your code and made sure that the slowness was coming from that for loop?

Comment: Unless you're doing it millions of times, 'faster' is meaningless

Comment: What's ProductIDs? An immutable array?

Comment: How many products do you have? Millions?

Comment: Products property is extremely slow to access because it is doing heavy processing (preexisting code).  So is that property called more times in a for loop than in the .Any enumeration?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First implementation is **slightly faster** (enumeration is slightly slower than `for` loop). Second one is **a lot more readable**.

---

### UPDATE

*Oded's answer is possibly correct and well done for spotting it. The first one is slower here since it involves database roundtrip. Otherwise, it is slightly faster as I said.*

---

## UPDATE 2 - Proof

Here is a simple code showing why first one is faster:

```
    public static void Main()
    {

        int[] values = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000).ToArray();

        int dummy = 0;
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        stopwatch.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            dummy *= i;
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Loop took {0}", stopwatch.ElapsedTicks);

        dummy = 0;
        stopwatch.Reset();
        stopwatch.Start();
        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            dummy *= value;         
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Iteration took {0}", stopwatch.ElapsedTicks);

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Here is output:

> Loop took 12198
>
> Iteration took 20922

**So loop is twice is fast as iteration/enumeration.**

Comment: I think the *slightly* you are referring to would be ridiculous to optimize against.

Comment: I offer facts, no more. I personally prefer second one.

Comment: However, the two are far from identical. See the call to `this.ProductIDs.Length` that occurs on every loop iteration and not at all in the `LINQ` query.

Comment: I think `foreach` and enumeration actually gives the compiler more optimization room to work with... at least that's what I remember from reading Effective C# way back in the .NET 1.1 days.

Comment: @Aliostad, I'm not disagreeing, just commenting for followup readers to understand the scope of the speed difference. ;)

Comment: See my updates. I tested and first one faster (although user's problem seems to be something else)

Comment: One run does not a profile make. Some runs, I bet the for loop comes out taking more ticks. May want to run this millions of times and take the average to accurately profile your proof.

Comment: Do it and then post the code. I have done, so you could too. Let's talk evidence...

Answer (score 9):

Call this an educated guess:

```
this.ProductIDs.Length
```

This probably is where the slowness lies. If the list of `ProductIDs` gets retrieved from database (for example) on every iteration in order to get the `Length` it would indeed be very slow. You can confirm this by profiling your application.

If this is not the case (say `ProductIDs` is in memory and `Length` is cached), then both should have an almost identical running time.

Comment: So the suggestion to prove this is to access ProductIDs.Length once and store it in a local variable, then put that variable in your for loop.

Comment: @Adam - Yes, _if_ that's the cause of the slowness.

Comment: @Oded yeah, I was merely commenting so the OP could see a possible way to exercise your idea.

Comment: This is the only possible solution, imo. I more likely suspect that this isn't the only change that was made or some external factor applies.

Comment: This was actually the problem in my case, although ProductIDs wasn't coming from a database.  There was a lot of horrible code associated with that property.  I marked Aliostad's as the answer since it answered the more general question of will a .Any provide greater performance than a for-break.  Will ProductIDs be accessed more times in a for loop than a .Any?

Answer (score 4):

I think they would be more or less identical. I usually refer to Jon Skeet's Reimplementing LINQ to Objects blog series to get an idea of how the extension methods work. Here's [the post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-10-any-and-all.aspx) for `Any()` and `All()`

Here's the core part of `Any()` implementation from that post

```
public static bool Any<TSource>( 
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate) 
{ 
   ...

    foreach (TSource item in source) 
    { 
        if (predicate(item)) 
        { 
            return true; 
        } 
    } 
    return false; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This post assumes that `ProductIDs` is a `List<T>` or an array. So I'm talking about Linq-to-objects.

Linq is usually slower but shorter/more readable than conventional loop based code. A factor of 2-3 depending on what you're doing is typical.

Can you refactor your code to make `this.ProductIDs` a `HashSet<T>`? Or at least sort the array so you can use a binary search. Your problem is that you're performing a linear search, which is slow if there are many products.

Answer (score 0):

I think the below implementation would be a little faster than the corresponding linq implementation, but *very minor* though

```
public bool ContainsProduct(int productID) {
    var length = this.ProductIDs.Length;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (productID == this.ProductIDs[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference will be generally in memory usage then speed.

But generally you should use for loop when you know that you will be using all elements of array in other cases you should try to use while or do while.

I think that this solution use minimum resources

```
int i = this.ProductIDs.Length - 1;

while(i >= 0) {
 if(this.ProductIDs[i--] == productId) {
   return true;
 }
}

return false;
```