# LINQ way to check Contains in a List (regardless of white spaces)

Tags: c#, linq

I have following code that checks whether userRoles collection has any of the values in authorizedRolesList. It does not work if the userRoleName has a whitespace.

What is the most efficient `LINQ` way for handling this?

CODE

```
        List<string> authorizedRolesList = null;
        string AuthorizedRolesValues = "A, B ,C,D";
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(AuthorizedRolesValues))
        {
            authorizedRolesList = new List<string>((AuthorizedRolesValues).Split(','));
        }

        string userRoleName = String.Empty;

        Collection<string> userRoles = new Collection<string>();
        userRoles.Add("B   ");

        bool isAuthorizedRole = false;
        if (userRoles != null)
        {
            foreach (string roleName in userRoles)
            {
                userRoleName = roleName.Trim();
                if (authorizedRolesList != null)
                {
                    //Contains Check
                    if (authorizedRolesList.Contains(userRoleName))
                    {
                        isAuthorizedRole = true;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

REFERENCE:

1. [When to use .First and when to use .FirstOrDefault with LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024559/when-to-use-first-and-when-to-use-firstordefault-with-linq)
2. [Intersect with a custom IEqualityComparer using Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340273/intersect-with-a-custom-iequalitycomparer-using-linq)
3. [Ignoring hyphen in case insensitive dictionary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829534/ignoring-hyphen-in-case-insensitive-dictionary-keys)
4. [C#: splitting a string and not returning empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393119/c-sharp-splitting-a-string-and-not-returning-empty-string)
5. [When does IEnumerable.Any(Func) return a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100393/when-does-ienumerable-anyfunc-return-a-value)
6. [Is IEnumerable.Any faster than a for loop with a break?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359092/is-ienumerable-any-faster-than-a-for-loop-with-a-break)

Comment: use Enumerable.Any<TSource> Method

Comment: The answers below pretty much cover it, however, if you have whitespace in the middle of a string (like "Role A") then .Trim won't work. It only removes whitespace from the beginning and end of a string.  You can use String.Replace(" ", "") to handle that scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess *most efficient LINQ way*  means most readable here.

The obvious way is to use [`StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions.aspx) when calling `Split()` and not storing the whitespace in the first place.

```
authorizedRolesList = AuthorizedRolesValues.Split(new []{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

---

But if for some reason you want to keep the additional whitespace or can't change the entries in `authorizedRolesList`, you can easily change your `if` clause from

```
if (authorizedRolesList.Contains(userRoleName))
```

to

```
if (authorizedRolesList.Any(x => x.Trim() == userRoleName))
```

---

BTW, talking about LINQ:

You could just replace your code with

```
bool isAuthorizedRole = userRoles.Any(ur => authorizedRolesList.Any(ar => ar.Trim() == ur.Trim()))
```

if you ensure `userRoles` and `authorizedRolesList` are not `null` (use an empty collection instead).

Even more readable IMHO would be something like

```
bool isAuthorizedRole = userRoles.Intersect(authorizedRolesList, new IgnoreWhitespaceStringComparer()).Any();
```

where `IgnoreWhitespaceStringComparer` would look like

```
class IgnoreWhitespaceStringComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        return x.Trim().Equals(y.Trim());
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        return obj.Trim().GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Does "Any" iterate through all the elements in intersect result? Or does it only check whether there exist a value?  [ I am referring to the `IEqualityComparer` approach]

Comment: `Any` iterates through the collection, but stops iterating when there's an element that satisfies the condition. So in the best case it has only to check the first element; in the worst case it has to check all elements.

Comment: In fact, I have one more requirement. I need to get the first matching   roleName. Is there a way to get it without storing the `intersect` result in a variable?

Comment: Then I suggest you use `userRoles.Intersect(authorizedRolesList, new IgnoreWhitespaceStringComparer()).FirstOrDefault()`. This will return the first matching rolename if any, and `null` when there's no match.

Answer (score 1):

just try like this remove whitespace when splitting string  and use Trim()

```
 List<string> authorizedRolesList = null;
    string AuthorizedRolesValues = "A, B ,C,D";
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(AuthorizedRolesValues))
    {
        string[] separators = {","};
        authorizedRolesList = new List<string>(
           ((AuthorizedRolesValues)
                  .Split(separators , StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                  .Select(x => x.Trim());
    }
```

and after this do use Trim() like this in below code

```
                //Contains Check
                if (authorizedRolesList.Contains(userRoleName.Trim()))
                {
                    isAuthorizedRole = true;
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just trim every entry in your list like so:

```
authorizedRolesList.ForEach(a => a = a.Trim());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        string authorizedRolesValues = "A, B ,C,D";

        var authorizedRolesList = authorizedRolesValues
            .Split(new[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(role => role.Trim());

        var userRoles = new Collection<string> {"B   "};

        bool isAuthorizedRole = userRoles
            .Select(roleName => roleName.Trim())
            .Any(authorizedRolesList.Contains);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about trimming the original list also?

`authorizedRolesList = new List<string>((AuthorizedRolesValues).Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()));`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
bool ifExists = userRoles.Any(AuthorizedRolesValues.Split(',').Select(val => val = val.trim());
```